# Prevent vlan and bridge interface rename to renameX form

Tags: networking, 16.04, systemd, network-bridge

Ubuntu 16.04 server.  Almost all vlan and bridge interfaces are renamed to the form renameX. How to prevent, or control the way interfaces are renamed?

I know that this is done by systemd, I know how to control for a physical interface, but unable to find the way to fix this problem for the logical interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

I have just run into this problem on OVH cloud instance using Ubuntu 16.04 as well. This release the renaming is done by systemd-udev process. On systemd handles the "Predicatable Network Interface Names" you can readup here: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/ .

To prevent vlan interfaces from being renamed I created `/etc/systemd/network/10-vlan.link`, here is the contents of it:

```
[Match]
Driver=*802.1Q*
[Link]
NamePolicy=kernel
```

Here is more about this (with examples): https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html

For it to change `NamePolicy` for bridge interfaces as well it will require expanding the `Driver` in `Match` section, like so:

```
[Match]
Driver=*802.1Q* bridge
[Link]
NamePolicy=kernel
```

but keep in mind I have not tested it with bridge interfaces, so no guarantees here.

Comment: It is very good that you've told about bridge.  It looks bridge works.  But I failed to get vlan working. Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried to change matching by OriginalName, tried to change priority - nothing helps.

Comment: If you want to debug `NamePolicy=` assignments run command:
    `sudo SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug udevadm test-builtin net_setup_link /sys/class/net/renameXX`
where `/sys/class/net/renameXX` - path to your interface [source](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found the driver was different in my server but this worked nicely for me, retaining the original eth names:

```
[Match]
OriginalName=eth*
[Link]
NamePolicy=kernel
```